# Is there's a way to do line by line combination of two files using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

Please see example:
Let's say I have File1.txt with three lines(a,b,c); File 2 also has 3 lines(1,2,3).

File1

```
a
b
c
```

File 2

```
1
2
3
...
```

I want to get A File3 like following:

File 3

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
...
```

Many thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `paste` doesn't do this.

Comment: Put the contents of the two files into arrays. Then use nested loops to print all the combinations.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's kind of like `join`, except there's nothing to join on. I don't think there's anything that makes a full cross-product.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `paste` would just output `a1 b2 c3`, not all the combinations.

Comment: Ahh. I missed that that's what they were doing. Different, indeed.

Comment: It looks like `join -j 2 file1 file2`, i.e., on a non-existing field, creates a Cartesian product. Just need to remove the space in the output.

Comment: Or like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25415883/3266847).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash 4.x:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^-- NOT /bin/sh

readarray -t a <file1   # read each line of file1 into an element of the array "a"
readarray -t b <file2   # read each line of file2 into an element of the array "b"
for itemA in "${a[@]}"; do
  for itemB in "${b[@]}"; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$itemA" "$itemB"
  done
done
```

On an older (pre-4.0) release of bash, you can replace `readarray -t a <file1` and `readarray -t b <file2` with:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a a < <(cat -- file1 && printf '\0')
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a b < <(cat -- file2 && printf '\0')
```