# How to Add Multiple Prefix to Multiple Paths

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files one has urls like

```
https://example.com/
https://example2.com/
https://example3.com/
```

and other file has paths

```
abc efg xyz
```

I am looking for output to be like this

```
https://example.com/abc
https://example.com/efg
https://example.com/xyz
https://example2.com/abc
https://example2.com/efg
https://example2.com/xyz
https://example3.com/abc
https://example3.com/efg
https://example3.com/xyz
```

I have tried this command, but its only doing for first url only

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p=$0; next} {print p  $0}' dodo.txt xoxo.txt

sed 'r dodo.txt' xoxo.txt | sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\/(.*)/\2\\1/'
```

How can i do it with bash/sed or awk

Comment: You want to get *Cartesian product* of lines from 2 files, therefore you should be able to adapt one of answers to your needs from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620946/cartesian-product-of-two-files-as-sets-of-lines-in-gnu-linux

Comment: Are the strings in the "other file" **really** space separated as shown in your question or are they actually 1 per line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` in the following manner:

```
[user@host ~]$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { for (i in a) print i $0 }' dodo.txt xoxo.txt
https://example.com/abc
https://example3.com/abc
https://example2.com/abc
https://example.com/efg
https://example3.com/efg
https://example2.com/efg
https://example.com/xyz
https://example3.com/xyz
https://example2.com/xyz
```

Which gives a slightly different order, but all the required lines.
I personally prefer using `join` for this task because the syntax is simpler:

```
[user@host ~]$ join -j 2 dodo.txt xoxo.txt | sed -e "s/\s//g"
https://example.com/abc
https://example.com/efg
https://example.com/xyz
https://example2.com/abc
https://example2.com/efg
https://example2.com/xyz
https://example3.com/abc
https://example3.com/efg
https://example3.com/xyz
```

Piping into `sed` to remove all whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `awk` and first load the file with the paths to split on the fields separator if the file paths file only has a single line:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  nr = split($0,a,FS)
  next
}
{
  for (i = 1; i <= nr; i++) {
    print $0 a[i]
  }
}
' paths.txt urls.txt
```

Output

```
https://example.com/abc
https://example.com/efg
https://example.com/xyz
https://example2.com/abc
https://example2.com/efg
https://example2.com/xyz
https://example3.com/abc
https://example3.com/efg
https://example3.com/xyz
```

If the paths file can have multiple lines, you can loop all the columns for all the path lines and add all the field values to an array which you can then loop for every url.

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    arr[++j] = $i
  }  
  next
}
{
  for (x = 1; x <= j; x++) {
    print $0 arr[x]
  }
}
' paths.txt urls.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/ /\n/;s/.*/g;s#$#&#p/mg' file2 | sed -ne h -f - file1
```

Convert file2 into a sed script and invoke it against file1.

Or perhaps use gnu parallel:

```
parallel -a file1 echo '{1}{2}' ::: $(cat file2)
```