# How can I do Cartesian Product using bash language？

Tags: bash

I have two files and each files has multiple lines. Now I want to combine each line in one file with every line in the other file in Linux using bash language. Of course, we can do this using python code:

```
from itertools import product

with open('fileA.txt', 'r') as fileA, open('fileB.txt', 'r') as fileB:
    linesA = fileA.readlines()
    linesB = fileB.readlines()

combined_lines = [f'{lineA.strip()}{lineB.strip()}' for lineA, lineB in product(linesA, linesB)]

with open('combined_output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('\n'.join(combined_lines))
```

This python code works well. But I want to know can I achieve it just using the bash command like `awk`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read multiple files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421972/read-multiple-files-in-bash) also [How to produce cartesian product in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363003/how-to-produce-cartesian-product-in-bash) and [Cartesian product of two files (as sets of lines) in GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620946/cartesian-product-of-two-files-as-sets-of-lines-in-gnu-linux)

Comment: Please only use language tags for the language *that the question is about*. A Python expert has no particular advantage in answering this question. Ideally problems should be described in a language-agnostic way. Aside from that, the `bash` tag is for questions about putting together a Bash script. It is not for questions about "any individual command that could do this, using any command that implements an appropriate mini-language". If you want to do it in `awk` then you should choose and ask about `awk` explicitly and tag the question as [tag:awk].

Comment: Please provide representative input files and corresponding expected output.

Comment: By the way, `awk` is not a Bash command. Awk is a language interpreter, just like Python is.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is in every language just nesting two loops, i.e. the outer loop iterates over the first data set, and for each data set the inner loop iterates over of the second data set. In particular in bash, this could be inefficient, in particular if the outer data set is large. You  could consider storing the data from the larger of the two sets into a bash array and iterate over the array elements.